# Using Caffe model with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, caffe

I am trying to use [yahoo nsfw](https://github.com/yahoo/open_nsfw) model with OpenCV. Here is what I have tried. I just copied `deploy.prototxt` and `resnet_50_1by2_nsfw.caffemodel` from the repository.

```py
import cv2 as cv
cvNet = cv.dnn.readNetFromCaffe('deploy.prototxt','resnet_50_1by2_nsfw.caffemodel')
image_path = 'adult.jpg'
image = cv.imread(image_path)
blob = cv.dnn.blobFromImage(image, 1, (224,224), (0,0,0), True, crop=False)
cvNet.setInput(blob)
detections = cvNet.forward()
print(detections)
```

Whatever image I have as an input I get an output like this `[[0.9855554  0.01444463]]`, the first value is always larger. 
I chose the image size `(224, 224)` because in `deploy.prototxt`, I found the following:

```
name: "ResNet_50_1by2_nsfw"
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Input"
  top: "data"
  input_param { shape: { dim: 1 dim: 3 dim: 224 dim: 224 } }
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you have managed to solve this problem already and I am not an expert on this, but I find very strange that you don't perform mean subtraction when creating the blob (the means are set to (0,0,0) in your code). Looking at the Github repository that you linked the authors do perform mean subtraction in `https://github.com/yahoo/open_nsfw/blob/master/classify_nsfw.py` line 114:

```
caffe_transformer.set_mean('data', np.array([104, 117, 123]))
```

This could have an impact if the classification of the network. I suggest using their parameters in your OpenCV implementation.

Comment: I suggest quoting directly the line 114 in the answer so it becomes more accessible to all SO users.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. I have edited the answer so that it includes that line. Thank you for calling it.